# Summing through an array containing other arrays

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop

I would like to sum through an array made of other sub-arrays.

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([1,2,3])
a2 = np.array([3,4,5])
a3 = np.array([6,7,8])

a = np.concatenate(([a1],[a2],[a3]))

print(len(a))

for i in range(1,len(a)):                                 (1)
    for j in i :                                          (2)
        for k in j :                                      (3)
            goal = np.sum(np.cos(k))
        print(goal)
        
   
        
goal  to achieve  : 

    goal = cos(1)+cos(2)+cos(3) 
    goal = cos(3)+cos(4)+cos(5) 
    goal = cos(6)+cos(7)+cos(8)
```

I thought of looping first on the array containing every other sub-array (1) , then for each sub-array (2) and finally inside each sub array (3) .

I'll get a traceback :

```
File "*****************", line 18, in <module>
    for j in i :

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

In my real problem, I might have more than 3 sub-arrays. I think it can be done but I'm still discovering Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have far too many levels of looping. You just need one loop to iterate over the rows of the array, then you can sum that row.

```
for row in a:
    goal = np.sum(np.cos(row))
    print(goal)
```

Comment: `np.sum` takes an axis argument that's much faster than looping over rows

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I suspected there was a numpy one-liner, but I don't know numpy well. I suggest you post that answer.

Comment: Simple, straightforward. Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
In [212]: a1 = np.array([1,2,3])
     ...: a2 = np.array([3,4,5])
     ...: a3 = np.array([6,7,8])
     ...: 
     ...: a = np.concatenate(([a1],[a2],[a3]))
     ...:
```

The resulting 2d array:

```
In [213]: a
Out[213]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

cos of each element:

```
In [214]: np.cos(a)
Out[214]: 
array([[ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 ],
       [-0.9899925 , -0.65364362,  0.28366219],
       [ 0.96017029,  0.75390225, -0.14550003]])
```

sum rows:

```
In [215]: np.cos(a).sum(axis=1)
Out[215]: array([-0.86583703, -1.35997393,  1.56857251])
```

it's easier to verify that this is summing rows with:

```
In [216]: a.sum(axis=1)
Out[216]: array([ 6, 12, 21])
```

With `numpy` it's best to think in terms of the whole multidimensional array, and actions that work on the whole thing, or on specific dimensions.  This is both faster and generally more useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explaination, I start to understand how numpy is working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `j in i` write `j in a[i]`

Comment: Where do you call `np.cos()`?

Comment: He doesn't want the sum of everything. He wants the sum of the cosines of each row.

Comment: Oh so the problem occurs when you try to cos and the list has another list?

Comment: Read the part of the question after "goal to achieve"

Comment: Now I see whats wrong

Comment: There are no lists, just numpy arrays.

Comment: See if this fixes it, I edited the answer